# Recuperar valores do JSON e montar HTML para cada registro

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, apache-cordova

Estou tendo dúvidas sobre como estruturar um `JQuery` que deve fazer o append de um código HTML para cada um dos itens que um JSON me retorna. Minha dúvida é como recuperar cada um dos valores do JSON e fazer uma estrutura de repetição para criar o código HTML que, por fim, será **impresso** na página. Está tudo bem simples pois estou aprendendo à trabalhar com `Phonegap`. Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Para exemplificar: Eu quero que para cada item retornado no JSON seja criado um Panel com o nome do país e do campeonato como o exemplo hardcoded da imagem: [image: Layout do App]

**webservice.js**

```
function listaCampeonatos(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/projetos/cjwebservice/listagem.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {type:'listaCampeonatos'},
    ContentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(response){
        alert('Listagem bem sucedida!');
        $('#resultado').html(JSON.stringify(response));
    },
    error: function(err){
        alert('Ocorreu um erro ao se comunicar com o servidor! Por favor, entre em contato com o administrador ou tente novamente mais tarde.');
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

}

**listagem.php**

```
include './conexao.php';

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$link = conectar();

if ($_GET['type'] == "listaCampeonatos") {
//echo 'Tipo de operação: ' . $_GET['type'] . '<br>';

$query = "SELECT c.id AS id_campeonato, c.nome_camp AS nome_campeonato, p.nome_pais AS nome_pais
              FROM tb_campeonato c
              LEFT JOIN  tb_pais p ON p.id = c.tb_pais_id
              LEFT JOIN  tb_partida pt ON pt.tb_campeonato_id = c.id
              WHERE pt.flag_ativo = 1

              GROUP BY p.nome_pais";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

$registros = array();

while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $registros[] = array('Campeonatos' => $reg);
}

$saida = json_encode(array('Lista' => $registros));

echo $saida;}
```

**jogos.html**

```
<!-- COTAÇÕES INÍCIO -->
    <div id="painel_partidas" class="panel panel-primary panel-heading-margin">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <center>
                <b>Brasil &raquo; Série A - 19/10/2016</b>
                <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#partida" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right"><i class="fa fa-compress"></i></button>
            </center>
        </div>

        <div id="partida">
            <div class="w3-border">

                <center>
                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="listaCampeonatos()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    Testar JSON
                    </button>
                </center>

                <div id="resultado"></div>

                <!--COTAÇÕES AQUI-->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- COTAÇÕES FIM -->
```

Comment: da um console.log(response) e ve como esse json é retornado, posta ele tbm

Comment: Log:  Object {Lista: Array[2]}                                     

 JSON:  {
"Lista":[
{
"Campeonatos":{
"id_campeonato":"630",
"nome_campeonato":"Copa do Mundo\r",
"nome_pais":"África\r"
}
},
{
"Campeonatos":{
"id_campeonato":"11",
"nome_campeonato":"Série A\r",
"nome_pais":"Brasil\r"
}
}
]
}

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi bem o que deseja, esta é a forma que utilizo para fazer uma busca no servidor e listar 4 produtos por linha na tela:

```
           listaProduto = function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Produto/ListaProduto',
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    linha = "";
                    if (data == "")
                        return;
                    var c = 1;
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        if (c == 1) {
                            linha = '<div class="row listagem-cachaca">';
                        }
                        linha += '<div class="col-sm-3 item-produto"><a href="/produto/' + data[i].URLPagina + '">';
                        linha += '<img src="' + data[i].EnderecoImagem + '" title="' + data[i].Descricao + '" alt="' + data[i].DescricaoAlternativa +
                                    '" width="' + data[i].Largura + '" height="' + data[i].Altura + '" class="img-responsive center-block" />';
                        linha += '<h4 class="nomeProduto">' + data[i].NomeProduto + '</h4></a>';
                        linha += '<p>' + data[i].Descricao + '</p>';
                        if (data[i].PrecoNormal == 0 || data[i].PrecoNormal == null || data[i].QtdVagas == 0 || data[i].QtdVagas == null) {
                            linha += '<p class="produtoIndisponivel">Produto Indisponível</p>';
                            linha += '<form action="/AssinanteContato/Aviseme" class="form-inline"  ' +
                                '  id="form' + i + '" method="get">';
                            linha += '<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" value="' + data[i].IdProduto + '" size="3">';
                            linha += '<div class="form-group"> ';
                            linha += '<input type="submit" value="Avise-me" class="btn btn-danger"></div></form></div>';
                        }
                        else {
                            if (data[i].PrecoNormal > data[i].PrecoAVista) {
                                linha += '<h4><strike style="color:red">De R$' + data[i].PrecoNormal.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',') + '</strike> <b>&nbsp;   Por R$ ' + data[i].PrecoAVista.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',') + '</b></h4>';
                            } else {
                                linha += '<h4><b>R$ ' + data[i].PrecoNormal.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',') + '</b></h4>';
                            }
                            linha += '<form action="/ClienteProdutoItem/Solicitar" class="form-inline" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-failure="FalhaAdicionarCarrinho"' +
                                ' data-ajax-success="SucessoAdicionarCarrinho" data-ajax-update="#carrinhoCompra" id="form' + i + '" method="post">';
                            linha += '<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" value="' + data[i].IdProduto + '" size="3">';
                            linha += '<div class="form-group"><label for="qtd">Qtd</label>';
                            linha += '<input class="input-sm" type="number" name="qtd"  value="1" min="1" size="3">';
                            linha += '<input type="submit" value="Adicionar" class="btn btn-danger"></div></form></div>';
                        }
                        if (c == 4) {
                            linha += '</div>';
                            $('.listaProduto').append(linha);
                            linha = "";
                            c = 0;
                        }
                        c++;
                    }
                    if (c > 0 && linha.length > 0) {
                        linha += '</div>';
                        $('.listaProduto').append(linha);
                    }
               }
           });
        };
        listaProduto();
```

Comment: Eu tentei fazer um simples teste e com a função e não deu certo. Ao que parece não entra no 'for' pois tem um 'alert' dentro do mesmo que não é acionado. Segue o código: http://pastebin.com/QqKzRBrM

Comment: Veja se o servidor está devolvendo em json. Pois se o response for um array json tem que entrar. Use o fiddler para fazer teste de envio e recebimento destes dados.

Comment: Essa é a resposta que eu recebo do webservice:

Object {Lista: Array[2]}
Lista
:
Array[2]
0
:
Object
Campeonatos
:
Object
id_campeonato
:
"630"
nome_campeonato
:
"Copa do Mundo
"
nome_pais
:
"África
"

Object
Campeonatos
:
Object
id_campeonato
:
"11"
nome_campeonato
:
"Série A
"
nome_pais
:
"Brasil
"

Comment: Está me parecendo que tem um array multidimencional, se for mesmo terá que ter um for dentro do outro, veja como recebo os dados no success de um array simples:
Array[4]
0:Object
 CODG_GRUPO:"38"
 DESC_GRUPO:"Disco"
1:Object
 CODG_GRUPO:"39"
 DESC_GRUPO:"Freio"
2:Object
3:Object
4:Object
length:4